# Elisp atomic types classification

Tags: types, elisp

I was trying to create a classification of atomic types in elisp, based upon this page: [Programming Types](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Programming-Types.html#Programming-Types).

Here is what I've done:

```
Atomic types:
1. Integer
2. Floating point
3. Character ≡ Integer
4. Symbol

   4.1 Keyword symbol

5. Array

   5.1. String
   5.2. Vector
     5.2.1. Bool vector
   5.3. Char table

6. Hash Table
```

Questions:

1. Is my classification full or I missed something?
2. Arrays and hash tables are considered atomic, despite the fact, that these objects can be divided further. Why?

Code:

```
(atom "aaa")
;> t

(atom [1 "two" (three)])
;> t

(atom (make-hash-table))
;> t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There are lacking keyword-symbol, such as `:keyword`. It's determined by `keywordp`.
2. I think `atom` is representing "not a list".

Comment: "I think atom is representing "not a list" - yes, I think it's an atavism from old times, when there were only 2 types in Lisp: atoms and lists. Actually, function and macro are also not an atom and not a list.

Comment: ok, I updated the question, adding "keyword symbol" to it. Now the classification is full.